# Problems setting root for cacti installation (nginx)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, monitoring, cacti

I'm having some problems getting my cacti installation to work. My root for content is /var/www/html. In this directory I have a subfolder "cacti" that points to /usr/share/cacti/site. In my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file I have added this section to the "server" block:

```
location /cacti {
    root cacti;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
```

I get a 404 when I go to mydomain.com/cacti

Where is (are) my mistakes with this config?

Comment: What happens if you delete the `root cacti;` statement?

Comment: @RichardSmith That did something... it gives me a 403 when I go to mydomain.com/cacti. When I went to mydomain.com/cacti/site it opened the web interface installation - I was able to complete it until it prompted me for admin user credentials. I entered them and it redirected me to https://example.com/cacti/auth_changepassword.php?ref=https://example.com/cacti/site/ which gave me a 404 again.

Comment: If `/cacti/site` opens the web interface, are you certain that your symlink points to `/usr/share/cacti/site` and not `/usr/share/cacti`?

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm pretty sure - in /var/www/html this is the command I executed:
`ln -s /usr/share/cacti/site cacti`